# set a value to null in cassandra with cql

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

How can I set a value of a row to null in cassandra?
For example I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE instruments (
                                              code text,
                                              ric text,
                                              primary key (code)
                                            )
```

if I want an element to have a particular `ric`:

```
update instruments set ric='test' where code='code';
```

But what about setting `ric` to `None`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be done with [`DELETE` CQL command](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#cassandra/cql_reference/delete_r.html):

```
DELETE ric FROM instruments WHERE code='code';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the value `null` in your queries. This was [added last year](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783) to CQL.

```
update keyspace.table set ric=null where code='code';
```

You can also use `null` in `insert` statements, but if you omit the value it's the same as saying `null` so there's no point.